# Any samples showing the use of OAuth2 service (server to server) accounts

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

All the samples I'v seen only support 'user' accounts where a user has to be present.

Looks like latest version of OAuth2 supports service accounts for server to server authentication where humans not present but I am struggling to find any libraries that support it or examples of in use.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't (yet) have any C# examples of authorization via service accounts, but the Google APIs support service account authorization flow. Here's an example of using this authorization flow with the Google BigQuery API, in Java & Python, using the Google APIs Client Libraries for these languages (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/ and http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/).

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery.Datasets;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.DatasetList;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;


public class BigQueryJavaServiceAccount {

  private static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery";
  private static final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId("XXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
        .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPE)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("my_file.p12"))
        .build();

    Bigquery bigquery = Bigquery.builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY)
        .setApplicationName("Google-BigQuery-App/1.0")
        .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();

    Datasets.List datasetRequest = bigquery.datasets().list("publicdata");
    DatasetList datasetList = datasetRequest.execute();
    System.out.format("%s\n", datasetList.toPrettyString()); 
}
```

Same snippet implemented in Python:

```
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

# REPLACE WITH YOUR Project ID
PROJECT_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
# REPLACE WITH THE SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL FROM GOOGLE DEV CONSOLE
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

f = file('key.p12', 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    key,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('bigquery', 'v2')
datasets = service.datasets()
response = datasets.list(projectId=PROJECT_ID).execute(http)

print('Dataset list:\n')
for dataset in response['datasets']:
  print("%s\n" % dataset['id'])
```